# testdriven.io flask-tdd-docker course chapter 15 pipeline stage test ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Tags: gitlab, testdriven.io

I am following python/flask/docker [tutorial](https://testdriven.io/courses/tdd-flask/advanced-ci/) . Everything worked perfectly until I pushed to GitLab the pipeline stage builds fine then fails on test stage:

```
  stage: test
  image: $IMAGE:latest
  services:
    - postgres:latest
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: users
    POSTGRES_USER: runner
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: runner
    DATABASE_TEST_URL: postgres://runner:runner@postgres:5432/users
  script:
    - python3.8 -m venv env
    - source env/bin/activate
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - pip install black flake8 isort pytest
    - pytest "project/tests" -p no:warnings
    - flake8 project
    - black project --check
    - isort project/**/*.py --check-only
```

The pipeline test logs:

```
$ pytest "project/tests" -p no:warnings
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-6.1.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /builds/piccoloa/flask-on-docker/project/tests, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 30 items
project/tests/test_config.py ...                                         [ 10%]
project/tests/test_ping.py .                                             [ 13%]
project/tests/test_users.py .............                                [ 56%]
project/tests/test_users_unit.py .............                           [100%]
============================== 30 passed in 0.41s ==============================
$ flake8 project
$ black project --check
would reformat /builds/piccoloa/flask-on-docker/project/api/users.py
would reformat /builds/piccoloa/flask-on-docker/project/tests/test_users.py
would reformat /builds/piccoloa/flask-on-docker/project/tests/test_users_unit.py
Oh no!   
3 files would be reformatted, 10 files would be left unchanged.
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Found this but don't know how to fix or if it ralates to problem.  "Adjust your threshold or improve coverage" mentioned in this [GitLab Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3104). I don't get any errors when I run the test on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. It seems to me that your CI is failing because `black` is finding files to reformat. It is possible that the version of `black` running in your CI is different than the one that runs locally, and therefore suggests new/different changes.

You could look through the output of your Gitlab pipeline for the version of `black` that is used there. If the version doesn't match your local version of `black`, try running your files locally through the version of `black` used by Gitlab, and then committing those changed files to your repo to trigger your CI.

Comment: I changed the pip install in CI to run same versions and still had issues.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a `build` stage prior to your `test` stage? Are you using a consistent version of `black` as you build the image that you later test?

Comment: when updated requirements.txt to match all lint checks it worked

Answer (score 0):

Not quite resolving failed job. As gitlab newbie, the only thing that worked for me since I get no errors when I run locally was to match the test stage pip python packages install in test scripts in requirements.txt and to comment out the flake8 and black tests scripts.